# MX records - same mail server on root and sub-domain name - possible?

Tags: dns, subdomain, root, domain-name, mx-record

i tried to search internet but not found answer.

On one domain name, in root and in a sub-domain name i have MX records pointing to the same mail server with same prios:

```
domain.com     in MX 10 mail-1.com
abc.domain.com in MX 10 mail-1.com
```

Zone was released without any errors, and now from external DNS check when i DNS-reverse: abc.domain.com i get this result:

```
abc.domain.com IN MX 10 mx.abc.domain.com
```

Crazy, isnt it?
am i missing something here?

- Maybe same MX servers cant be connected to @ and sub-domain?
- or maybe i should set different prios and it will work correctly?
- or simplest: if MX is connected to root, there is no need to add it to sub-domain?

thanks for help!

Comment: What does "from external DNS check when i DNS-reverse: abc.domain.com" mean, maybe you can rephrase?

Comment: setting in the domain panel at the domain name provider versus for example: http://network-tools.com/ when i check how the DNS for this domain name resolves

Answer (score 1):

> MX record is a type of resource record in the Domain Name System that
>   specifies a mail server responsible for accepting email messages on
>   behalf of a recipient's domain

So answers to your points:

- of course, mail servers can handle multiple different domains. I am certain that `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM` is set as MX record for thousands of domains
- priorities don't matter here, thyy are used in case you have multiple MX records for the same domain
- you need `MX` for subdoman only if you intend to receive emails for something@sub.domain.com addresses

(Troubleshooting any issues/mismatch will be difficult without real domain name)